# RVM on ubuntu12.04 vps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
~# curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0     11      0  0:00:16  0:00:15  0:00:01  1057
100  9979  100  9979    0     0    317      0  0:00:31  0:00:31 --:--:-- 20235
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0      8      0  0:00:15  0:00:15 --:--:--   384
100   125  100   125    0     0      1      0  0:02:05  0:01:33  0:00:32     0curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/tarball/stable'.
  curl returned status '7'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here:
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/804